# Multiple Apache virtualhosts on same server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, centos6

I am trying to setup a virtualhost / redirection point so i can have two different systems on one site.

so far this is what i have:

```
NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.207:80
NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.207:1500
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost 89.104.220.207:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/******/html
     ServerName www.******.dk
     ServerAlias ******.dk
     ErrorLog /var/www/*****.dk/logs/error_log


</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 89.104.220.207:1500>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
     DocumentRoot /var/www/******/
     ServerName *******
     ServerAlias ******.dk
     ErrorLog /var/www/*****.dk/logs/error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

My idea here is that if i go to 89.104.220.207:1500 then i should open `/var/www/foo/`

However this doesnt seem to work: when I try to enter the I for the foo nothing happens or well I get an error. If you go to 89.104.220.207:1500 you will see that you get an error.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: well when i try to enter the ip for the system_learningbank nothing happens or well i get an error.

if you go to 89.104.220.207:1500 you will see that you get an error

Comment: Do you have `Listen 1500` in your config?  Also, check firewalls.

Comment: @garethTheRed when i do this and restart i get the following Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 89.104.220.207 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 28 21:55:28 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.207:1500 has no VirtualHosts
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:1500
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:1500
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: @garethTheRed distro?

Comment: im using CentOS 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `apache` to listen on a non-standard port you need to add the `Listen` directive to `httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 1500
```

---

On `SELinux` protected machines, this will cause `apache` to fail to start as `SELinux` will block access to all non-standard http ports.

To resolve this:

```
# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 1500
```

then confirm it's added with:

```
# semanage port -l | grep '^http_port_t'
http_port_t                    tcp      1500, 80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443
```

Note:  `semanage` is in the `policycoreutils-python` package.

`apache` should now start and the virtual host should work on the non-standard port.

---

Remember that when using a non-standard port, your firewall may need to be opened:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1500 -j ACCEPT
# service iptables save
```